# Class Point\Inheritance - task check

Tags: python, class, inheritance, math

I'm trying to solve the tasks (text below), but I have a problem with the second point, i.e. method in it that displays the length of the segment and the positions of the start and end points.-
I don't really know how to write it, Could someone look at the code and give some hints?

- Define a Point class with x, y fields and a method displaying the
  point's position (eg "point (2,3)").
- Then create a class Segment that will inherit from the class point.
  Create a method in it that displays the length of the segment and the
  positions of the start and end points.
- Then define the Triangle class which will contain 3 Points,
  automatically determined 3 Sections (walls) of them and included a
  method for displaying the surface area of the perimeter.

code:

```
from math import sqrt, hypot


class Point:
   def __init__(self, x_init, y_init):
       self.x = x_init
       self.y = y_init

   def __str__(self):
       return "Point(%s,%s)"%(self.x, self.y)


class Segment(Point):
   def distance(self): **!-probably a badly written method**
       return ((self.x ** 2) + (self.y ** 2)) ** 0.5

   def position(self, p): **!-probably a badly written method**
       dx = self.x - p.X
       dy = self.y - p.Y
       return hypot(dx, dy)


class Triangle(Point):
   def __init__(self, x, y, z):
       Point.__init__(self, x, y)
       self.z = z

   def __str__(self):
           return "Point(x %s ,y %s, z %s )" % (self.x, self.y, self.z)

   def __area__(a, b, c):
       s = (a + b + c) / 2
       return (s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)) ** 0.5

   def __perimeter__(a, b, c):
       s = (a + b + c)
       return s
```

Comment: The assignment is very misguided. `Segment` shouldn't inherit from `Point`. It should be a container of two points.

Comment: Your instructor doesn't know the difference between `IS-A` and `HAS-A` relationships between classes.

Comment: however, the task says that the Segment must inherit from the Point class, unless it can be done, only written differently

Comment: suggestion for string formating is to use `f strings` as for the problem: in Segment class You have to initiate inheritance: can use sth like this: `Point.__init__.(self, x_init, y_init)` also You should create the `def __init__(self)` in Segment class.

Comment: Your `Segment` class always uses the origin as the start point.

Comment: I know what the task says, but it makes no sense.

Comment: Triangle shouldn't inherit from `Point`. As the task says, it "contains 3 points"

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I will try to correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task 2 is just wrong. `Segment` needs to contain 2 points, so it can't inherit from `Point`. It should be:

```
class Segment:

    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def distance(self):
        dist = ((self.start.x - self.end.x) ** 2 + (self.start.y - self.end.y) ** 2) ** 0.5
        print(f"distance from {self.start} to {self.end} is {dist}"
```